# Django Template Not Extending

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to extend a base template in Django named 'base.html' in my main page 'index.html' and it does not work as expected. Rather than extending the template, the page just displays {% extends 'base.html' %}, plus the HTML in index.html when displaying the index page.

The 'base.html' page sits in the root of my templates folder and my 'index.html' page sits in templates/pages.

In 'base.html':

```
{% load static %}
...some code...
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
...some code...
```

In 'index.html':

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
...some code...
{% endblock %}
```

In views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html')
```

In settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [{'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates)]
```

Expected Result:

```
Navbar
Content
```

Actual Result:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
Content
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is the URL you see on your browser? Are you using the development web server or a dedicated one such as nginx/apache?

Comment: I'm using the dev server on my localhost. `http://localhost:63342/APPNAMEL/rfl/templates/pages/index.html`

Comment: I don't think that is the dev server URL. It looks like you are directly browsing your `index.html` using another web server, that (as expected) does not parse Django templates. What port do you see when you start your dev web server using `python manage.py runserver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others mentioned, you are most likely viewing the html file directly.

You need to go to a `view` that makes use of the template which will render the final html.

I am not familiar with your project structure, so try doing this first:
in `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]
```

and copy your `index.html` to the root of your templates folder.

then browse to `http://localhost:63342`, once you have it working, then you can work your way out to suit your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not opening the base.html template. The view function points to the the child data file.  When I remove the extends statement from that, the child block data displays.  So it is that Django is not interpreting the extends statement in the data file correctly when it exists.  I can find no discussion of what might cause that to happen. And no error messaging.  Kind of makes a deal breaker out of django.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably opening the template itself rather than calling the development server. If Django has a problem with any of those things, it throws an error. It does not spit out the template code.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.